# Uninstall Windows 10 and install Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, uninstall

A friend would like to use Ubuntu 14-4 or 15-10, but the OS on his laptop in Windows 10. When I put the ISO from one or the other in his dvd-drive, it starts up, but after a short while Windows overrides it. I want to install Ubuntu without Windows. I can not find any solution for this problem, also because I'm not used to Windows. I did take the hard-drive out of the laptop and connected it with my pc with a usb-tool. It appeared, that the drive can not be opened with anything, so I can not delete the files on it.
Please tell me how to proceed.

Comment: Please try Disabling "**Secureboot**" (in BIOS) on your friends laptop

Answer (score 0):

First of all : Copy all your personal data you want to keep to another drive.
Boot into Windows, open command prompt as administrator and execute:

```
powercfg /h off
```

Open Windows Control Panel -> Power Settings and uncheck Fast Startup.
Important : Shutdown the machine completely and do NOT restart the PC.

Boot from the Ubuntu installation media you have created before.
Select 'Try Ubuntu without installing' to boot into the Live desktop.

Open GParted (to do it press the Windows key and type GParted).
Right-click and delete all partitions on the disk, one after the other.

Create a new partition - format it with fat32 - choose a size of about 300 MB.
Create a new partition - format it with ext4 - choose a size of minimum 20 GB.
Create a new partition - format it with swap - choose a size matching the RAM.

On the desktop click Install Ubuntu - when asked what to do, choose 'Something else'.
Select the ext4 partition you had created with GParted for the Ubuntu system before.
Select **/** as mount point and ext4 file system as format ... start the Ubuntu installation.